# CodeIgniter: Two Model-Methods in a row cause Internal Server Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm pretty new to CodeIgniter and trying to get my first project done. I have two ajax db-update functions which (for themselves) work totally fine.

(because the queries as such work, I simplify for the sake of this example:)

```
    public function updateA($data) {

            $this->pos1    = $data['pos1'];
            $this->pos2    = $data['pos2']; 

            $this->db->where('id', 1);

            $result = $this->db->update('tablePos', $this);
    }
```

and

```
    public function updateB($data) {

            foreach ($data as $value) {

                    $this->name    = $value['name'];
                    $this->type    = $value['type']; 
                    $this->db->where('id', $value['ID']);

                    $result = $this->db->update('tableNames', $this);
            }

    }
```

As mentioned **both of them work like a charm if I call them in my Controller 'alone'**. So like

```
$this->MainModel->updateA($data);
```

OR

```
$this->MainModel->updateB($data);
```

but NOT

```
$this->MainModel->updateA($data);
$this->MainModel->updateB($data);
```

Then the first query is executed but not the second. It makes no difference which one I call first. In case I call both in a row only the fist is executed and my ajax function gets back a

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I spend the whole last night searching - no clue... :(

EDIT:

I now isolated everything into a test case:

CONTROLLER:

```
        public function parse()
    {
            $this->load->model('MainModel');

            $position =  '{"ID":1,"pos1":5,"pos2":6}';
            $position = json_decode($position, true);

            $names =  '[{"ID":1,"name":"AAAA","type":9},{"ID":2,"name":"BBBBB","type":2},{"ID":3,"name":"CC","type":4}]';
            $names = json_decode($names, true);

            $this->MainModel->updateA($position);
            $this->MainModel->updateB($names);
    }
```

MODEL:

```
        public function updateA($data_a) {
            error_log("----------- start A -----------");
            $this->pos1    = $data_a['pos1'];
            $this->pos2    = $data_a['pos2']; 
            $this->db->where('id', 1);
            $result = $this->db->update('tablePos', $this);
            error_log($this->db->last_query());
            error_log("----------- stop A -----------");
    }


    public function updateB($data_b) {
            error_log("----------- start B -----------");
            foreach ($data_b as $value) {

                    $this->name    = $value['name'];
                    $this->type    = $value['type']; 
                    $this->db->where('id', $value['ID']);

                    $result = $this->db->update('tableNames', $this);
                    error_log($this->db->last_query());
            }
            error_log("----------- stop B -----------");
    }
```

Error-log result with BOTH update calls:

> [03-Dec-2015 14:13:15 Europe/Berlin] ----------- start A -----------
>
> [03-Dec-2015 14:13:15 Europe/Berlin] UPDATE `tablePos` SET `pos1` = 5, `pos2` = 6 WHERE `id` = 1
>
> [03-Dec-2015 14:13:15 Europe/Berlin] ----------- stop A -----------
>
> [03-Dec-2015 14:13:15 Europe/Berlin] ----------- start B -----------

RESULT for

```
    $this->MainModel->updateA($position);
    // $this->MainModel->updateB($names);
```

> [03-Dec-2015 14:23:23 Europe/Berlin] ----------- start A -----------
>
> [03-Dec-2015 14:23:23 Europe/Berlin] UPDATE `tablePos` SET `pos1` = 5, `pos2` = 6 WHERE `id` = 1
>
> [03-Dec-2015 14:23:23 Europe/Berlin] ----------- stop A -----------

RESULT for

```
    // $this->MainModel->updateA($position);
    $this->MainModel->updateB($names);
```

> [03-Dec-2015 14:25:14 Europe/Berlin] ----------- start B -----------
>
> [03-Dec-2015 14:25:14 Europe/Berlin] UPDATE `tableNames` SET `name` = 'AAAA', `type` = 9 WHERE `id` = 1 [03-Dec-2015 14:25:14 Europe/Berlin]
>
> UPDATE `tableNames` SET `name` = 'BBBBB', `type` = 2 WHERE `id` = 2
>
> [03-Dec-2015 14:25:14 Europe/Berlin] UPDATE `tableNames` SET `name` = 'CC', `type` = 4 WHERE `id` = 3
>
> [03-Dec-2015 14:25:14 Europe/Berlin] ----------- stop B -----------

It just stops. No Error. And the error-log DOES show other php-errors when I provoke them. So this is absolutely mysterious to me ...

Comment: Just change your model function passing variable name to `updateB($b_data)` and `updateA($a_data)`.

Comment: Check your error logs for the actual full error and callstack - post it in your question#

Comment: In fact this is already the case. Both methods get send array-vars with different names... :(

Comment: There is no php-error thrown (error reporting is on!) I tried to figure out where the program stops by placing error_log() messages in the functions. The script just stops when the query is fired. No error, no writing wo logfile...

Comment: `print_r($data)` and post the value of it!!

Comment: if you are seeing `500 (Internal Server Error)` in your ajax response, then there is an error, and you should see something in the logs

Comment: your controllers have to return something to the ajax

Comment: I edited the post and added some details...

Comment: can't be that nobody had this problem before ... Is there any other approach to this? do I have to reset the db-connection in between the two calls? or something like that? :/

Comment: In your `updateB()`  function can you print the value of  `$this` before acually updating the record ??

Comment: `[03-Dec-2015 15:48:44 Europe/Berlin] ----------- start A -----------`

`[03-Dec-2015 15:48:44 Europe/Berlin] UPDATE `tablePos` SET `pos1` = 5, `pos2` = 6 WHERE `id` = 1`

`[03-Dec-2015 15:48:44 Europe/Berlin] ----------- stop A -----------`

`[03-Dec-2015 15:48:44 Europe/Berlin] ----------- start B -----------`

`[03-Dec-2015 15:48:44 Europe/Berlin] AAAA`

`[03-Dec-2015 15:48:44 Europe/Berlin] 9`

 .... sorry no line breaks possible ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing you methods to use local variables instead of class property `$this`   like so :

```
public function updateA($data_a) {
            error_log("----------- start A -----------");
            $this->db->where('id', 1);
            $updateData = array(
                               'pos1' => $data_a['pos1'],
                               'pos2' =>  $data_a['pos2'],
                           ); 
            $result = $this->db->update('tablePos', $updateData);
            error_log($this->db->last_query());
            error_log("----------- stop A -----------");
    }
```

and

```
  public function updateB($data_b) {
            error_log("----------- start B -----------");
            foreach ($data_b as $value) {
                  $updateData = array(
                               'name' => $value['name'],
                               'type' =>  $value['type'],
                           ); 
                    $this->db->where('id', $value['ID']);

                    $result = $this->db->update('tableNames',$updateData);
                    error_log($this->db->last_query());
            }
            error_log("----------- stop B -----------");
    }
```

A possible reason may be because the class properties initialized when model is loaded.

For the second call when you update using `$this`, the class still holds the properties which were used during first update and as they are not required here,they are causing errors.

However i am not sure how these values are not reflecting in the queries that you logged.

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add a comment, so I'll add my comment here.

In the Codeigniter documentation says

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#anatomy

**Where Model_name is the name of your class. Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase**

and the name of your model does not comply with this rule.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no solution. I renamed it to Main_model but the result is the same. Looked promising though!